# How do I apply the DRY principle to iterators in C++? (iterator, const_iterator, reverse_iterator, const_reverse_iterator)

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator, dry, code-reuse

OK, so I have two (completely unrelated, different project) classes using iterators now. One has `iterator` and `reverse_iterator` working as intended, and the other, current one has `iterator` and a semi-broken `const_iterator` (specifically, because const_iterator derives from iterator, the code `LinkedList<int>::iterator i = const_list.begin()` is valid and allows you to modify the const defined list...).
I intend to add all four types to this class... If I can.

How would I proceed to minimize copy/pasting code and changing only the return type? Create a base class like `base_iterator` to inherit from? Create an `iterator` or `const_iterator` and inherit from that? Inherit from some std:: class? If any of these cases are the "best" approach, what code goes where?
Perhaps none of the alternatives are good? I'm quite lost here, and can't find much reference material.

Any advice is appreciated, but please keep in mind that I'm new to the subject (both iterators and C++ in general, especially OOP). I've tried, in vain, to study the header files shipped with GCC - they're not exactly the tutorial I'm looking for.

Comment: Stdlib implementations are, in general, poor choices to learn from, for any language.  They often need to deal with external interfaces (e.g. the OS, other languages), might need to be backwards compatible with code from last decade, and other factors that simply don't apply to you.  In sum: they are not written with teaching as a goal.  A good book is a must and will serve you much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, blanket application of the so-called DRY rule ([Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), for those who aren't familiar) is not the best approach. Especially if you're new to the language (C++ and iterators) and OOP itself (methodology), there's little benefit in trying to minimise the amount of code you need to write *right now*.

I would implement the two iterators using appropriate code for each of them. Perhaps after you have more experience with the language, tools, and techniques, *then* go back and see whether you can reduce the amount of code by factoring out common code.

Comment: Have you had to repeat the definition of DRY so much that you do it reflexively now? :P

Comment: Probably sound advice, and I took it. I made two separate base classes, iterator and const_iterator (both subclasses of std::iterator), and based reverse_iterator on iterator, and const_reverse_iterator on reverse_iterator. The total line count for the iterators came to ~70-75. Not bad for 4 different types. That's excluding the upcoming inline documentation, but including enough whitespace to make it readable. :)

Comment: While "implement first, refactor later" seems like good *general* advice, this answer seems like a cop-out for implementing iterators, where it should be well-known what code often gets duplicated.  While `iterator` and `reverse_iterator` might have significant differences in implementation, `iterator` and `const_iterator` *should* be mostly identical (at least for any sane implementation).

Answer (score 3):

It's actually extremely simple.

First of all, take a look at [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library.

Second: you need to declare a base class (it's well explained in the example how to proceed) that will be similar to this one.

```
template <class Value>
class BaseIterator: boost::iterator_adaptor< ... > {};
```

You implement the operations to move your pointer around there. Note that because it's an adaptation over an already existing iterator, you can implement it with only a few strokes. It's really impressive.

Third, you simply typedef it with the const and non-const versions:

```
typedef BaseIterator<Value> iterator;
typedef BaseIterator<const Value> const_iterator;
```

The library explictly show you how to make the `const_iterator` version be constructible from the `iterator` version.

Fourth, for the reverse thing, there is a special [reverse_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iterator/doc/reverse_iterator.html) object, that is built on a regular iterator and move backwards :)

All in all, a really elegant and yet fully functional way of defining iterators on custom classes.

I regularly write my own container adaptors, and it's less about DRY than simply saving myself some typing!

Comment: +1 for boost::iterator_adaptor. I use it too and it work great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make iterator derive from const_iterator instead of the other way around.  Use `const_cast` appropriately (as an implementation detail, unexposed to users).  This works very well in the simple cases and models that "iterators are const_iterators" directly.

When this *starts* to require clarification comments in your code, then write separate classes.  You can use localized macros to generate similar code for you, to avoid repeating the logic:

```
struct Container {
#define G(This) \
This& operator++() { ++_internal_member; return *this; } \
This operator++(int) { This copy (*this); ++*this; return copy; }

  struct iterator {
    G(iterator)
  };
  struct const_iterator {
    G(const_iterator)
    const_iterator(iterator); // and other const_iterator specific code
  };
#undef G
};
```

That the macro is scoped/localized is important, and, of course, only use it if it actually helps you—if it results in less readable code for you, type it out explicitly.

And about reverse iterators: you can use `std::reverse_iterator` to wrap your "normal" iterators in many cases, instead of rewriting them.

```
struct Container {
  struct iterator {/*...*/};
  struct const_iterator {/*...*/};

  typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
  typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList<int>::iterator i = const_list.begin()` What does your begin method look like? By studying the STL you can see that containers define two such methods with the following signatures:

```
const_iterator begin() const;
iterator begin();
```

You should not have a problem getting an `iterator` from an object qualified as const. I don't think DRY applies here.

Comment: He currently (incorrectly) has const_iterator derive from iterator, so with the usual const/non-const overloads for begin, his code is still able to implicitly convert any const_iterator to an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Once I used the following approach:

1. make a template class common_iterator
2. add typedefs for "iterator" and "const_iterator"
3. add to "common_iterator" a constructor taking "iterator" type

For "iterator" the additional constructor will replace default copy constructor, in my case it was equivalent to default copy constructor.

For "const_iterator" it will be an additional constructor which allows to construct "const_iterator" from "iterator"

Answer (score 0):

A more concrete version of [what maxim1000 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776918/179715):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Container, bool forward>
class iterator_base
{
public:
    using value_type =
        typename std::conditional<std::is_const<Container>::value,
                                 const typename Container::value_type,
                                 typename Container::value_type>::type;

    iterator_base() { }

    // For conversions from iterator to const_iterator.
    template<typename U>
    iterator_base(const iterator_base<U, forward>& other)
    : c(other.c)
    {
        // ....
    }

    value_type& operator*() const
    {
        // ...
    }

    iterator_base& operator++()
    {
        if (forward)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    iterator_base& operator++(int)
    {
        iterator_base copy(*this);
        ++*this;
        return copy;
    }

private:
    Container* c = nullptr;
    // ...
};

using iterator = iterator_base<self_type, true>;
using const_iterator = iterator_base<const self_type, true>;

using reverse_iterator = iterator_base<self_type, false>;
using const_reverse_iterator = iterator_base<const self_type, false>;
```